# How to manage frustum culling

Tags: terrain-rendering, webgl, frustum, three.js

I have a **spherical clipmap** based planet terrain. The entire planet is made from a **ring geometry of 1 unit** which the vertex shader moves to cover the entire planet of 6 million unit radius. But the planet gets culled whenever the starting point for this geometry isn't in the camera's view (which is 99.9999% of the planet).

What's the best solution for making sure the planet is viewable even when the original mesh isn't?

This is based on **WebGL and Three.js**.

Comment: Is there even any point in culling the entire planet?  I presume part of it's going to be in view almost all the time.  However, if you google "sphere frustum clipping" you should find plenty of articles on the subject.

Comment: Right, don't cull the entire planet, just the surface triangles.

Comment: I'm not culling the planet on purpose. I'm asking how I can keep it from being culled whenever the 1 meter ring geometry isn't in view.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to set the boundingSphere attribute on the original geometry to the radius of the planet. Now even though only the vertex shader moved triangles are in view, I can still see the planet.